# XSLT: Test if current element matches variable xpath

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I have a dynamic xpath string being supplied to a template, and I wish to test whether the current element matches that xpath within the template.

I've tried using `<xsl:evaluate/>`, but I'm not sure how exactly it's used, or if its even the right tool for the job.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
        xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"
        version="2.0">
    <!-- HTML output -->
    <xsl:output
            method="text"
            encoding="UTF-8"
            omit-xml-declaration="yes"
            standalone="yes"
            indent="no"
            media-type="string"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <!-- This xpathMatches variable will be dynamically generated -->
        <xsl:variable name="xpathMatches" select="'s4|s2[@class=''class1'']|d3'"/>

        <xsl:apply-templates mode="test">
            <xsl:with-param name="xpathMatches" select="$xpathMatches" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="test">
        <xsl:param name="xpathMatches"/>

        <xsl:variable name="xpathEval">
            <xsl:evaluate xpath="$xpathMatches" context-item="."/>
        </xsl:variable>
        
        <!-- This doesn't work-->
        <xsl:if test="$xpathEval">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:transform>
```

Input:

```
<div>
    <s1 />
    <s2 class="class1"/>
    <s4 class="class7"/>
</div>
```

Desired Output:

```
s2
s4
```

Since s2 and s4 match the xpath, only those element names should be returned.
But currently the test is returning true for all elements.

Comment: Not sure what exactly "matches" means in this scenario. Your string represents a **relative** path; thus it will only match the actual path when evaluated from the context of `div`. I don't see how the stylesheet is supposed to know that.

Comment: Why would `s4` not be selected by the path or pattern in `<xsl:variable name="xpathMatches" select="'s4|s2[@class=''class1'']|d3'"/>`? As commented correctly earlier, your relative paths only make sense in the context of the `div` elements, but in that case the `s4` element should be selected like the `s2` element.

Comment: Yes, s4 should be selected as well. I didn't write the desired output correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, xsl:evaluate is new in 3.0. Your stylesheet specifies 2.0. That isn't going to make it fail, but it's confusing.

XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 offer no standard way of evaluating an XPath expression constructed dynamically as a string, though some processors offer extension functions for this purpose.

The use of `xsl:evaluate` is correct here, what's wrong is your use of `xsl:variable`. With no `as` attribute, `xsl:variable` is constructing a document node, and the effective boolean value of a document node is always true. The only change you need is to add `as="node()*"` to the `xsl:variable` declaration.

**== LATER ==**

Although the code will now do something, it doesn't do what you described as your requirement: "test whether the current element matches that xpath within the template". Your XPath expression makes a downward selection from the context item, so it will never select the context item itself. I guess what you really want is to treat this expression as an XSLT pattern, and test the context item against this pattern. But there's no facility in XSLT 3.0 to match against a pattern supplied dynamically as a string.

What you could do here is to test whether the context item C has some ancestor A which, when used as a context item for evaluating the expression, includes C in its result. To achieve that, wrap the expression `$xpathMatches`:

```
<xsl:evaluate xpath="'exists(ancestor-or-self::*!(' 
  || $xpathMatches ||
  ') intersect .)'"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you handle things at a template matching `div` you want something like

```
  <xsl:template match="div">
    <xsl:variable name="xpathMatches" select="'s4|s2[@class=''class1'']|d3'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="matched-nodes" as="node()*">
      <xsl:evaluate context-item="." xpath="$xpathMatches"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$matched-nodes/name()" separator="&#10;"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Note that `xsl:evaluate` is an optional feature, you will find it supported in Saxon 10 all ediditions, Saxon 9.8 and 9.9 PE and EE, Saxon-JS 2 and Altova XML 2017 R3 and later if recollection serves me right.

In the limited case that you know the path when you want to run the stylesheet and can use and set a static parameter before compiling the XSLT the use of a shadow attribute and static param might suffice:

```
  <xsl:param name="xpathMatches" select="'s4|s2[@class=''class1'']|d3'" static="yes" as="xs:string"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="div">
    <xsl:value-of _select="({$xpathMatches})/name()" separator="&#10;"/>
  </xsl:template>
```